# Get a photo in Google Contacts API call

Tags: python, xml, google-cloud-platform, google-contacts-api

I am using the following call to get all contacts:

```
CONTACTS_DATA_URL = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/%s/full?max-results=20000" % email
```

And here is what an entry looks like in the response:

```
<entry>
    <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/samspade%40gmail.com/base/1234</id>
    <updated>2016-07-19T19:25:23.314Z</updated>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
    <title type='text'>Sam Spade</title>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/samspade%40gmail.com/667132947e96a0/Y3eM8hrGJoL8p2F5MvkoFw'/>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/samspade%40gmail.com/667132947e96a0'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/samspade%40gmail.com/full/667132947e96a0'/>
    <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/samspade%40gmail.com/full/667132947e96a0/1468956323314001'/>
    <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='samspade@primary.com' primary='true'/>
</entry>
```

Is there a way to get the photo in the contacts entry? I've tried all the links but none of them return anything I can view. I'd like to get all photos in one call (like the getAllContacts call), without having to iterate over 10,000 entries and get all photos for each:

https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/#contact_photo_management), you can `GET` a request to the contact's photo link URL.

From your request, there's no `gd:etag`.

> **Note**: If a contact **does not have a photo**, then the photo link element
>   **has no `gd:etag`** attribute.

Sample:

```
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*'
    href='http://google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/liz%40gmail.com/c9012de'
    gd:etag='"KTlcZWs1bCp7ImBBPV43VUV4LXEZCXERZAc."'/>
```

And there's no certain request to call all contacts from your list. To retrieved a contact's photo, you must specify the `userEmail` and `contactId`:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
```